# MIN IF Function that ignores blank or 0s in cells

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to return a list of the oldest dates based on two critera.

I currently have the following basic formula returning the oldest date based on 2 criteria.

```
=MIN(IF('Sheet1'!A7:A650='Input Summary'!B46,IF('Sheet1'!D7:D650=C46,'Sheet1'!L7:L650)))
```

However When I expand the range, it covered blank cells so always returned `00/01/1900` as there is no date.

I've tried using the `=ISNUMBER()` before the `IF` starts but it still returns the `00/01/1900`.

Expanding this to exclude blank cells is the end goal, any assistance would be great!

Comment: Try to use `ISBLANK` instead of `ISNUMBER`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a third:

```
=MIN(IF('Sheet1'!A7:A650='Input Summary'!B46,IF('Sheet1'!D7:D650=C46,IF('Sheet1'!L7:L650>0,'Sheet1'!L7:L650))))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Worked Perfectly, Thanks Scott!